# RecyclerView looking like in Google Play app

Tags: android, tabs, material-design, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to make app design like Google Play/Movies.

I already made and customised SlidingTabs accroding to this example:
https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/project.html

To display different layouts at each Tab I use this code with differemt R.layout_pager_item:

```
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.pager_item,
                    container, false);
            container.addView(view);
            TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
            title.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1));
            return view;
        }
```

But when I add:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

to the R.layout_pager_item I have the Error:
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(boolean)' on a null object reference

And RecyclerView covers all my Tabs and I see only TollBar and my RecyclerView.

How are organised Tabs and RecyclerView?

Now I use this code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ContentFragment extends Fragment{

    private static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String KEY_INDICATOR_COLOR = "indicator_color";
    private static final String KEY_DIVIDER_COLOR = "divider_color";
    private static final String ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER = "arg_page_number";

    int pageNumber;

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private MyAdapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private ArrayList<String> items;


    public static ContentFragment newInstance(CharSequence title, int indicatorColor,
            int dividerColor, int page) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putCharSequence(KEY_TITLE, title);
        bundle.putInt(KEY_INDICATOR_COLOR, indicatorColor);
        bundle.putInt(KEY_DIVIDER_COLOR, dividerColor);
        bundle.putInt(ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER, page);

        ContentFragment fragment = new ContentFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        pageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        switch (pageNumber){
            case 0:
            case 1:
            case 2:
                return inflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_item, container, false);
            mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) mRecyclerView.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
            mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

            mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

            items = new ArrayList<String>();

            mAdapter = new MyAdapter(items);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                mAdapter.add("Title: " + i);
            }

            case 3:
                return inflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_item2, container, false);
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        }
    }
```

Abd have error with LinearLayout managerm it works only with ActionBarActivity. but when I change from Fragment to ActionBarActivity then getArguments stop working

Comment: without proper code, we cant help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see many errors in Fragment, change `onCreateView()`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_item, container, false);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    items = new ArrayList<String>();

    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(items);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);          
    mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        mAdapter.add("Title: " + i);
    }
    return view;
}
```

I don't know what other classes you have (your ViewPage, SlidingTab, Adapters, etc).

Comment: you are absolutely right.
Now no mistakes and works.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You need a `Viewpager` with all the tabs.
And each tab is a Recycler View with the list of elements